# Can't see spoilers on touchscreen

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, spoilers

I asked about it on [meta.scifi.stackexchange.com](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/how-to-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen) and they told me to post it here.  Probably need to add the `:active` to the `:hover` meta class or something like that.

Example:

> Hammer Time

Comment: @Kobi, thanks for the edit, the scifi guys had me thinking that only existed on their site and gaming for some reason.

Comment: @balpha can this be fixed for the main site?  The mobile site is pretty ugly on an iPad (presumably designed for smaller screens), so "use the mobile view" isn't really a great solution for this problem.

Comment: Seconding Tony's comment.  I was attempting to use scifi.se on an iPad and copying and pasting/the mobile site are both pretty unfortunate workarounds.

Comment: @TonyMeyer this is now ["fixed"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108090/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen-outside-of-mobile-site/237663#237663).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new mobile sites support this:

[image: Click to show spoiler on mobile site]

Beware that the spoiler text is only hidden after the page has loaded...

(Click the "mobile" link at the bottom of this page to see it in a regular browser too.)

Comment: How is "mobile" detected? If it's by user agent, what happens when a privacy-enabled mobile browser strips off that value?

Answer (score 9):

Using the Android browser, this works just fine; it honors the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Mobile Safari however does not. Adding `:active`, as you suggested, doesn't work either (I just tested it).

So on your iPod, you're stuck with copying the text to the clipboard (tap and hold the spoiler box, then "copy") and pasting it somewhere else (e.g. in a note).

Comment: good work around. BTW, how did you add :active on mobile safari?

Comment: @Peter Turner: I added it on my local development version and looked at it via iPod.

Comment: oh - I didn't realize you were a dude :-)  Was hoping there was a firebug for iPod...

Comment: I cannot verify, but some claim that nowadays [tapping initiates hover on the iPad too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129343/how-do-i-view-spoilers-on-an-ipad), and hence can be used to show spoilers.