# Can't see spoilers on touchscreen outside of 'mobile' site

Tags: bug, status-completed, usability, spoilers, touch-screen

Spoiler text can't be made visible on a touch screen.

This was already pointed out ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen) as well as [elsewhere](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134/how-to-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen)).  However, that was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by providing the ability to see spoiler text in the mobile version of the site.

(SE seems to be using the same definition of "mobile" as Facebook does: a little phone device.  These are not the only devices that are mobile!).

This is not a good solution.  If I have a large-screen touch device (an iPad, an Android tablet (although this [might work already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen/75660#75660) and there are only about 10 of them anyway), a Windows 8 touch-only device, a Kindle Fire, a TouchPad, etc) then I don't want to use the "mobile" version of SE - it looks like crap on a large screen.

Please provide a way to unspoiler text on the real StackExchange sites.

Comment: You could try [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com), which not only provides a mobile interface that looks nice on tablets but also should display spoiler text.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison thanks, but the point here is that StackExchange sites look fine and work perfectly on a touch-based interface, **except** that you can't read spoiler text.  We don't want a different interface, we want the bug with this one fixed.

Comment: I thought in your question you mentioned that you didn't *like* the mobile interface.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison no, I don't like the mobile interface.  I want the interface that I have already (i.e. the same thing that you'd see if you were using an old-fashioned mouse-based system), **but where spoilers can be revealed with touch**.

Comment: Re your "might work": Yes, it woks just fine in the Android browser, both on phones and on tablets.

Comment: @Tony: Ah, I get what you're saying now. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: I feel adding some "Click/tap here" (just like on the mobile theme) would also solve issues with [people not knowing about spoilers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104085/differentiate-spoilers-from-empty-block-quotes) to start with.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the current "hover to show spoiler" functionality, the next build will allow clicking spoiler blocks to show them.

Works on latest iPad Safari (the only device I tested on).

Answer (score 5):

Just above each spoiler there should be a small piece of text such as: *Click/Tap to see spoiler* (depending on whether the device is touch-enabled), or some other visual indicator.

Not only would this be a huge usability improvement for iPad and other touch device users (like myself), but it would also help new users with a mouse.
The first time I saw a spoiler (using a mouse) I was confused by the small rectangle of colour, not realising what it was or what I was supposed to do.