# Spoiler markdown results not working correctly on iPad

Tags: bug, ipad, spoilers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't see spoilers on touchscreen outside of 'mobile' site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108090/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen-outside-of-mobile-site)

The spoiler markdown `>!` output does not seem to be working on iPad. I see no way of making the hidden text visible.

Touching, tapping, swiping, multi-fingered touching/tapping/swiping, licking, poking, prodding - nothing seems to work!

I'm using a first-generation iPad with iOS 5.01, but have observed this since 4.2. I'm also using Safari.

Also, is *meta.stackoverflow.com* the correct place to report Stack Exchange platform bugs? I've primarily noticed this problem on the sci-fi SE and haven't tried it elsewhere, but I would imagine the same is true for other SE sites.

Comment: I'm using the standard theme.