# Cannot view spoilers on iPad when logged in

Tags: bug, ipad, spoilers

I am viewing this question on my iPad: [Is there an explanation for Amy Pond's selective remembering of people?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14882/3383)

How do I view the spoilers on the question?

There is no way for me to "hover over" the spoiler - neither tapping nor sliding works to show the spoilers...

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Open this question on an iPad **not using the mobile site** (I am on an iPad 2)
2. If you're not logged in, log in.
3. Tap the grey block below:

   > Test me!
4. Note that you can't see the super-sensitive spoiler in that gray block.
5. Log out, and repeat step #3
6. Wallow in the disappointment that comes from having a secret spoiled.

#### Analysis

There seems to be an event discrepancy between being logged in and being logged out:

[image: a screenshot of a DOM event inspector]

[Tim Stone theorizes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129343/cannot-view-spoilers-on-ipad-when-logged-in#comment415716_129343) that this is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Side note, tapping is how you get all the on-hover events to trigger, like the flag/vote buttons for comments

Comment: Another side note: on the mobile theme, usage is very clear. But the iPad is using the regular site. One more reason to want the mobile look & feel for spoilers [on the regular sites too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104008/could-we-please-have-a-level-two-arrow-of-hiding/104016#104016)!

Comment: As one needs to scroll code blocks with 2 fingers (or at least it used to be like that): does using 2 fingers help?

Comment: @Arjan nope, none of that works.

Comment: More specifically, you can only click to view the spoiler if the "Was this post useful to you?" controls are present, apparently. I'm unclear why that makes a difference at the moment.

Comment: @TimStone found an extra mouseover/out event when you are logged out.

Comment: Apparently (seemingly contrary to the documentation) setting the `mouseover` event on a non-`document` element causes that element to be activate-able, which allows you to trigger the hover behaviour of the descendant elements. It's worth noting that in your screenshot the event handler isn't actually applied to the spoiler by the way (it's applied to `div#question.question`), you just have the filter on the right hand side of the Event Listeners panel set to "All nodes"

Comment: @TimStone interesting. Did not know about the filter. But still, why should that affect the hover event?

Comment: It makes the post element something you can "click" on in iOS, which in turns allows you to trigger the hover behaviour of the spoilers. The fact that you can click the spoilers on iOS at all is an accidental side-effect of that handler being added for the post feedback feature, so in the general case showing the spoiler on an iPad is simply unsupported and likely needs to be reworked to make that more touch-screen friendly.

Comment: For a bug report that's gotten a fair bit of attention, this is currently rather useless. Things I would like to know: 1) Has anyone other than AmanaP reproduced this? 2) Has *anyone* reproduced this **reliably?** 3) Does this affect all three iPads? 4) Does this affect current (iOS 6) versions of Safari? 5) Does this affect tablets that aren't iPads? 6) If you switch to the mobile theme (using the link in the footer) does that correct the problem?

Comment: @Shog9 it has been tested on all tablets when **logged in** tapping on the spoiler **does not work**. When logged out, it works fine. See discussion on KennyTMs deleted answer.

Comment: @Shog9 switching to the mobile theme makes no sense! that is completely different. I am talking about using the main site **not** the mobile one.

Comment: @Shog9: last I checked, I'm not amanaP. This bug can be reproduced 100% reliably: just log in on an iPad, any iPad. (And anyone who seriously wants people to use the mobile theme on an iPad needs to get their head out of certain parts of their anatomy.)

Comment: AmanaP, @Marti: you seem to be taking this rather too personally. I don't care which theme you use, and I can't test this myself - I just want a clear, comprehensive bug report. I've done as much as I can to flesh this out with the information that was here, so if you can fill in the blanks I've identified above, that will go a long way toward making this something worth discussing.

Comment: @Shog9 would editing this question to include the questions asked above move it towards being fixed? I am willing to put in the legwork to file a good bug report. Just confirm that the above is what you need and I'll make it happen. :)

Comment: Whether or not this gets fixed depends on what the fix is, how hard it is to implement, and how many people want it, @ahsteele. When I first found this report, *none* of that was at all clear - hence my questions.

Comment: @shog9 would you say it is clear now? i.e. do you need this info? Don't want to do the work if it's not needed.

Comment: I've done my best to make it clear by editing; I'm still not entirely sure why it happens, but at least there's a theory.

Comment: @Shog9 it has something to do with an extra event when not logged out... not sure why though...

Comment: (I don't have an iPad to test this on, so I'm limited in what I can do to help; I made it as clear as I can when I last reviewed it)

Comment: @Shog9 I believe it is the same on any touch device (but I could be wrong...)

Comment: All I have is a Kindle Fire, and it works just fine on that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make this as another answer. I truly don't understand why someone can tap on the spoiler and someone can't.

Anyway, we could force all spoiler blocks to respond to taps using the scriptlet:

```
javascript:$('.spoiler').click(function(){this.style.color='black'})
```

> Test me

> Test me

> Test me

Comment: #1: this seems like a hack (especially if I **not** want to see all spoilers). #2 ehhhh

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: #1. See the update, it will not show all spoilers until you click. #2. Well it **is** a hack :), Safari should respond to `:hover`. Maybe we should blame Apple.

Comment: Have you tested this again? It seems that they have fixed this bug.

Comment: `this.style.color`. ;)

Comment: @Purmou: Fixed :)

Comment: @KennyTM there is a bug. the reason why some cannot is because they are **logged in** on the iPad.

Comment: Months later why has this not been fixed? It's a **HUGE** user experience fail.