# How do I view spoilers in an “About Me” on an iPad?

Tags: bug, profile-page, spoilers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot view spoilers on iPad when logged in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129343/cannot-view-spoilers-on-ipad-when-logged-in)

On an iPad, viewing spoilers in questions and answers works just fine (Just tap on it).

> See? It works!

But for some reason, [in the “About Me” section of a profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174964/anish-gupta), they don't work (normally anyway).

Is there another way to view them in an About Me or is it impossible.

**Disclaimer:** This is **NOT** a duplicate of [How do I view spoilers on an iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129343/how-do-i-view-spoilers-on-an-ipad). This question is specifically about About Mes.

Comment: I'm not an official person in any way (hence using a comment instead of an answer) but I would guess that this is by design. Spoilers were introduced for a very specific use case, and it has nothing to do with About Me blocks. I don't see why they should even be allowed there.